# Disable code coverage of auto-properties by NCrunch

Tags: c#, code-coverage, visual-studio-2015, automatic-properties, ncrunch

Recently I've moved to Visual Studio 2015. I use NCrunch for checking code coverage, which I also upgraded. The main difference that I noticed was that NCrunch now also includes coverage auto-properties, which wasn't the case with Visual Studio 2013. I suspect this has something to do with the new C# language features for auto-properties, but I'm not using them for my project.

What is a good way to have NCrunch ignore coverage of auto-properties without making any changes to the code?

Comment: There's a workaround at the linked duplicate.